# Android Studio not showing SDK Manager and AVDManager in the Tools Menu after update to 3.4

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.4

In `Android Studio` after update to 3.4 when I select the Tools menu, The `SDK Manager` and `AVD Manager` option is not shown .

Also, when I search for `SDK Manager` using the search setting. in file menu it shows the `SDK Manager` option but not accuses from tools menu.
So, what can I do for access to `SDK Manager` or `AVD Manager`?

Answer (score 0):

I realized with the review in Android Studio 3.4, this problem occurred,that there were two file in the SDK folder with the names: (AVD Manager.exe ) and (SDK Manager.exe ) 216KB in size , with the removal of them the Android Studio problem was resolved.